# Spring 3 standalone application does not write output to file

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I have a Spring 3 standalone application and I'm using log4j for logging. Log4j settings are the ones in the xml that is pasted below. I get log output writen to console but nothing is writen to log file.

Log4j is initialized in class *Main* by statement:

```
DOMConfigurator.configure("abanol-loader-log4j.xml");
```

I've already tried by changing loggers level values, by changing value of attribute *additivity* in logger *file* and even by removing it. I get output writen to console but nothing is writen to log file (but it is created).

I've validated XML file successfully, I've googled for a solution but I get nothing. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" threshold="debug" debug="false">

   <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="abanol-loader.log"/>
      <param name="MaxFileSize" value="25MB"/>
      <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p-%d{ISO8601}-[%t]-%C.%M:%L(%c{1}) - %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <logger name="es.pack1.mypackage" additivity="true">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="file"/>
      <appender-ref ref="console"/>
   </logger>

   <logger name="org.springframework" additivity="true" >
      <level value="WARN"/>
      <appender-ref ref="file"/>
   </logger>

   <logger name="net.sf.jasperreports" additivity="false">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="file"/>
   </logger>

   <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="console"/>
      <appender-ref ref="file"/>
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Is the file created at least? If you don't specify an absolute path for the log file, it gets created under `user.dir` (system property).

Comment: Yes, log file is created but it remains empty. However, it's created under execution folder instead.

Comment: I've replaced XML configuration by properties finally and it has worked although same settings are specified.

Answer (score 0):

You have configure both "The Console Appender" and "RollingFile Appender" in your log4j.xml

So, Log4j defaultly selects the first. i.e, Console Appender as the logging.

So, it was writting the log report in Console(System.out.println)

Please remove the Console Appender, then it will automatically save the log's in the File...........

Comment: I thought that it could log on several appenders... I will try your suggest. thanks!

Comment: I've removed console appender from both root and es.pack1.mypackage loggers. I'm surprised that output is written to console still but nothing is writen to log file. I think that something is wrong in my log4j settings; I will check it again. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced log4j XML configuration by a properties file finally. I think it's same than XML that I was using but it works while XML doesn't. I really don't know why.

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, S, file

log4j.logger.es.bod.freenergy.abanol=DEBUG, file

log4j.appender.S = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.S.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.S.layout.ConversionPattern =%5p-%d{ISO8601}-[%t]-%C.%M:%L(%c{1}) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File =abanol-loader.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize = 10Mb
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=25
log4j.appender.file.Append = false
log4j.appender.file.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p-%d{ISO8601}-[%t]-%C.%M:%L(%c{1}) - %m%n
```

Thanks to who has answered my question anyway.